# How to separate a comma separated values string and save row by row in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which looks like following

| group | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4 |
| 2 | 3,7,5,9,8 |

These comma-separated values are string type.

I want to convert it to the following table.

| group | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 8 |

Do we have any function to do the following in PostgreSQL?
What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `regexp_split_to_table()` for this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6de820b8a2ccdb0580611b344c44f5c5)

```
SELECT
    group,
    regexp_split_to_table(id, ',')
FROM mytable
```

This function splits the column data at the (regexp) given delimiter (the comma in your case) and transforms the split parts into separate rows.

If you want to use the id values directly after the expand, it can be useful to put this function into the from list:

```
SELECT
    "group",
    id_elements
FROM mytable,
    regexp_split_to_table(id, ',') as id_elements
```

(The comma is a shortcut for `LATERAL CROSS JOIN` in that case)